# Why are there conflicts when pulling changes to a local branch after a pull request has been merged at the remote?

Tags: git, version-control

From my `develop` branch I create a `feature` branch and make some changes. After all my changes have been made I squash all my commits so that only 1 commit message is added after the merge like so, `git reset --soft HEAD~X & git commit & git push -f`, where `X` is the number of commits to squash.

A pull request is then created and the `feature` is successfully merged into `develop` without any conflicts. I then wish to update my local `develop` branch, so I do the following `git checkout develop & git pull`.

There are conflicts, why is this, and how might I avoid them?

Note that there have been no changes made to the local copy of `develop` in this scenario.

Comment: There's something missing from the scenario as explained. I can't say what, but in exactly the scenario you described the pull would be a fast-forward and conflicts would be impossible.  Did you locally merge your `feature` to `develop` prior to the pull? That could lead to a conflict (between your local merge and the remote one trying to make the same changes)...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I've updated the scenario, maybe my way of squashing commits caused issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it’s fast forward pull as Mark said.

If there has conflict, it’s mainly caused the `develop` branch has been force changed (squash, rebase etc). Before you pull changes from remote `develop` branch to local `devlop` branch, you can check by below commands:

```
git fetch origin develop
git log develop..origin/develop --oneline
git log origin/develop..develop --oneline
```

If `git log origin/develop..develop --oneline` has output, that means the `develop` branch commit history has been changed by others.

Answer (score 0):

> There are conflicts, why is this, and how might I avoid them?

Someone else has committed code that cause it.
In order to avoid it try to use `pull request` is you can, all major servers support it and you will see the conflicts before its being merged.

The best way to handle it is to pull `developer` into your feature `branch` very frequently. This will lower the possibility of having conflicts.

If you wish to run "dry run" before merging you can this (depend what is your current checked-out branch)

```
git log ^branchA branchB

git log ^develop feature
git log develop ^feature
```

Comment: It seems to me this doesn't match the facts presented.  OP says he *did* use a pull request (so the merge would've occurred remotely) and indicated that the local `develop` had not moved from the previous `origin/develop`; if that's true any conflict from another developers' changes would not occur locally.  Note in particular OP states that `feature` merged to `develop` *without conflict*, so needing frequent merges from `develop` to `feature` wouldn't be the issue.